# How to interpret color cheme in android telegram theme - .attheme

Tags: colors, themes, telegram

I want to write an application that will help set up a theme for telegram (android). But I can not figure out how to interpret the colors recorded in the file .atheme. Many attempts did not lead to anything.

For example: in .attheme, the color is written as -6576209, referring to rgba #9B9DAFFF or 155 157 175 255.

How can these values relate to known color schemes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for my questions. It use methods from default class Color from android sdk for encoding and decoding colors.

Here used methods:

```
public static int argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {
    return (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}

public static int rgb(int red, int green, int blue) {
    return (0xFF << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}

public static int alpha(int color) {
    return color >>> 24;
}

public static int red(int color) {
    return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

public static int green(int color) {
    return (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

public static int blue(int color) {
    return color & 0xFF;
}
```